# Unable to Create ORACLE-ODBC DSN on Window 7 64 bit using SysWow64/odbcad32.exe

Tags: excel, odbc, vba

I am trying to create a DSN but I can't  do it. The processes I am applying these are as follows:
            1. Oracle 12c (64bit) Installed in Remote PC
            2. Using Oracle 12c Client on Windows 7 64 bit
            3. Trying to Create DSN from Syswow64/odbcad32.exe becuase I want to use this DSN from my Excel 2013 VBA program and the office is 32 bit.
            3. After pressing the Add button on the Microsoft ODBC Administrator from Syswow64/odbcad32.exe, I don't find the
Oracle In OracleClient12Home2 in the driver list.

Please suggest me what should I do in this regard.

Comment: install odbc driver?

Comment: I have installed Oracle 12c Client. I can make DSN from System32/odbcad32.exe. Please help me.

Comment: did you install `32`bit client?

Comment: Yes, I install 32 bit client

Comment: Thank you for your helping. I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this. Basically due to security reason, my registry was not configured properly at the time of installation. I have removed my previous installation and Set new ORACLE_HOME and run install As Run As Administrator. After that the problem is solved.